# How do I use a stream extraction operator if a default constructor isn't provided?

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I have a software engineering question in relation to C++, constructors (default and otherwise), the stream extraction operator, and reference member variables. I know that is a lot of topics, but all of them seem to depend on each other in this problem.

For a problem that I am trying to solve, I wanted to make a `Vec` class which holds the data for the problem, and a `ProblemSolver` class which will eventually have methods to solve the problem. The `ProblemSolver` class doesn't make sense without the data, so I wrote it with a copy of the `Vec` data (considerations for reference member occurred later...). So here was what my first version looked like:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vec {
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    Vec(const int s) : v(s, 0) { }
};

class ProblemSolver {
private:
    Vec data;
public:
    ProblemSolver(Vec d) : data(d) { }
};

int main() {
    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    Vec v(m);
    ProblemSolver ps(v);
}
```

So far this seemed okay. Then I though that I should provide stream extraction operators for each class so that the objects could be in charge of reading in its own data instead of reading it in main. So I rewrote the classes like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vec {
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    Vec(const int s) : v(s, 0) { }
    friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& input, Vec &V ) {
        int m;
        input >> m;
        V.v = std::vector<int>(m, 0);
        return input;
    }
};

class ProblemSolver {
private:
    Vec data;
public:
    ProblemSolver(Vec d) : data(d) { }
    friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& input, ProblemSolver &P ) {
        input >> P.data;
        return input;
    }
};

int main() {
    ProblemSolver p;
    std::cin >> p;
}
```

This is where I ran into some confusion because the first line of `main()` is trying to call the default constructor for `ProblemSolver`. I understand that it's an issue because one isn't provided, but what should I really do about this in terms of good practice for my problem above? Should I always provide a default constructor, even though the class doesn't make sense without an actual set of data? Was I wrong that I should just let the object handle its own data reading, and that I shouldn't write the stream extraction operators?

Because of [this article](http://soggywizards.com/tips/code/c++/memory-management/parameters/refmembers.html#:%7E:text=Reference%20member%20variables%20are%20used,lifetime%20of%20your%20class%27%20objects.), I considered using a reference member variable instead because the "data for the problem solver class still exists outside of the existence of the instances of the problem solver". So I again rewrote it like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Vec {
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    Vec(const int s) : v(s, 0) { }
    friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& input, Vec &V ) {
        int m;
        std::cin >> m;
        V.v = std::vector<int>(m, 0);
        return input;
    }
};

class ProblemSolver {
private:
    const Vec& v;
public:
    ProblemSolver(const Vec& v_) : v(v_) { }
};

int main() {
    int m;
    std::cin >> m;
    Vec v(m);
    ProblemSolver p(v);
}
```

But with this, I still can't write a stream extraction operator for `ProblemSolver` and the one written for `Vec` is practically useless because I'd have to instantiate a `Vec` object before I can use the stream extraction operator. Therefore in the example above I still have to read the `int m` data in `main()` and I can't do something like `Vec v; std::cin >> v; ProblemSolver p(v);` for the same reasons as in the second code segment. I think it should be possible to do something like instantiating and reading in a variable all at once like `std::cin >> ProblemSolver p;`, but obviously that isn't the case.

So my primary question is how do I properly write these two classes? Should I include default constructors? My understanding is that I shouldn't provide a default constructor if the class doesn't make sense without any data, but is that wrong? If I don't write a default constructor, should I instantiate a class with useless data provided to the standard constructor just so that I can then use the stream extraction operator on it? That seems like a bad practice to instantiate an object falsely before stream extraction.

To be clear, I'm not just looking for just a solution that works. I'd like to develop actual good practice and techniques for situations like these, so please support your answer with justification.

Comment: An unfortunate design limitation of stream extraction operators is that they only work for objects that can be assigned to, so if you are determined to provide them for `ProblemSolver` there's no getting around the need to add a default ctor (or its moral equivalent -- some way to construct a `ProblemSolver` instance in some "default" state that you will immediately overwrite). If all you want is to enable `ProblemSolver` to initialise itself from a stream, just add a ctor that takes a `std::istream` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the object must be constructed first.

Some options are:

- have a default costructor which construts with a default value (maybe 0).
- have a constructor which takes reference to `istream` which will then use it to load values.

so something like:

```
class Vec {
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    Vec(const int s) : v(s, 0) { }
    Vec(std::istream& input) 
    {
        int m;
        input >> m;
        v = std::vector<int>(m, 0);
    }
    friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& input, Vec &V ) {
        int m;
        input >> m;
        V.v = std::vector<int>(m, 0);
        return input;
    }
};


class ProblemSolver {
private:
    Vec v;
public:
    ProblemSolver(Vec v_) : v(v_) { }
    ProblemSolver() : v(0) { }
    ProblemSolver(std::istream& in) : v(in) { } 
};
```

If you are adamant that the class will not make sense without a value, you will be better of writing a generator function and abandoning the stream extraction operator. like so:

```
class Vec {
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    Vec(const int s) : v(s, 0) { }
};

class ProblemSolver {
private:
    Vec data;
public:
    ProblemSolver(Vec d) : data(d) { }
    static ProblemSolver generate()
    {
        int m;
        std::cin >> m;
        return ProblemSolver{Vec{m}};
    }
};

int main() {
    ProblemSolver p = ProblemSolver::generate();
}
```

Comment: For now, I am using a combination of the two above: a static generator with an istream& as input. I am worried about that though for two reasons: (1) the stream extraction overload returns the original stream and I can't with the generator because I'm already returning the object [not sure if that will be a problem], and (2) I am worried that the return of the object in the generator is return by copy (slower) and is only avoidable by NRVO. Thoughts?

Comment: @redmoncoreyl regarding problem (2) see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision here it is stated that from c++17 onwards, this particular type of copy elision is mandatory.

Comment: @redmoncoreyl regarding concern (1) in this case there is no need for returning `std::istream&`, the `<<` operator returns a reference to enable chaining, this is not required here.